# question in regards to the difference in application between connecting visual studio to mysql using server explorer and implementing a post request

Tags: c#, visual-studio, server

I am trying to understand the implication between connecting your visual studio application to a server using the built in server explorer and implementing a post request.

I know for a fact that you generate a URL using post request method which could essentially connect to the server hosting the database and modify it,
and on the other hand, I can also use the built-in server explorer for visual studio that essentially directs the application to the server hosting the database.

I would like to know if my understanding so far is correct and what are the pros and cons of these two and which is more appropriate to use.

And also,

string connectionString = @"server=localhost;userid=root;password=__;database=sys";
MySqlConnection conn = null;

in the first parameter for connection string, does it also accept server url and not just server name?

Comment: MySql does not have a webpage (URL).  You would have to write one.  The connection string uses a driver on your PC to make the connection.   The Net Library MySQL know the name of the driver and makes the connection to the driver which send the commands and response to the database.  MySql is a file and the driver opens the file.

Comment: ah ok that make sense thank you for that so then in terms of a live server. should i still be using connection string and server explorer?

Comment: What are you using the server explorer for?  Only debug code or something else?